# Is it possible to attach multiple schedule/cron events with one AWS Lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, cron, serverless-framework, serverless

Currently my lambda function works successfully with one schedule event attached to it. Relevant excerpt from my template.yaml:

```yaml
Resources:
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: HelloWorldFunction
      Handler: helloworld.App::handleRequest
      Runtime: java11
      MemorySize: 512
      Environment:
        Variables:
          PARAM1: VALUE
      Events:
        CronHourlyEvent: # This already works
          Type: Schedule
          Properties:
            Description: Send John Doe
            Enabled: True
            Schedule: "cron(0 0/1 * * ? *)"
            Input: !Sub '{"name": "John Doe"}'
```

Lambda is triggered every one hour here and it works fine.

Now I would like to add another schedule event that triggers same lambda once a day at 12 Noon. One way of doing it would be to create a separate lambda and attach daily schedule event to that, but I don't want to create a new lambda just for that. I was hoping if I could attach two schedule events to the same lambda.

I could not find any example online where more that one schedule events were attached to a lambda, but I think following addition in template.yaml file would be needed:

```yaml
Resources:
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: HelloWorldFunction
      Handler: helloworld.App::handleRequest
      Runtime: java11
      MemorySize: 512
      Environment:
        Variables:
          PARAM1: VALUE
      Events:
        CronHourlyEvent: # this was already present
          Type: Schedule
          Properties:
            Description: Send John Doe
            Enabled: True
            Schedule: "cron(0 0/1 * * ? *)"
            Input: !Sub '{"name": "John Doe"}'
        CronDailyEvent: # added this
          Type: Schedule
          Properties:
            Description: Send Jane Doe
            Enabled: True
            Schedule: "cron(0 12 1/1 * ? *)"
            Input: !Sub '{"name": "Jane Doe"}'
```

I want to test it locally, so I downloaded and configured sam-sdk. But I don't think that supports running cron jobs locally. I was able to trigger events manually, but couldn't find any provision to run schedule jobs automatically based on cron expression provided.

So I would like to know:

1. Whether we can attach 2 or more schedule/cron type events to an AWS lambda function?
2. If yes, are the code changes I have done correct?

This will go directly into production, and I can't seem to figure out a way to test it locally.

Comment: 1. Yes you can. 2. I'm not sure about serverless framework, but I think you would have to create independent `AWS::Events::Rule` resources for extra events.

Comment: Also, you're asking here because you can't make these changes because it would go straight to production (which I won't even start as to why that flow is wrong) but you know you could just create a new template with a test lambda/rules and deploy that to non-prod to see if it works?

Comment: Just make the rule trigger the lambda every hour on the hour, then it will trigger at 12 noon every day anyway? Completely agree with above comment you should have a test environment.

Comment: @404 I think this is the way to go, a lambda for testing is doable. Thanks

Comment: @AnonymousAlias Both rules are doing different things, the one that runs hourly is an inexpensive operation. The other one is a time consuming, clean-up kind of operation. That's why running it only once a day.

Comment: I don't understand though it's 1 lambda so it should be doing the same thing when it's automatically triggered? Is it because you will send a different input for each event then have logic in the lambda based on that? It sounds like you should probably have 2 separate lambdas. It is best practice to keep lambdas for small single purpose executions they are inexpensive to spin up.

Comment: @AnonymousAlias I have to send different inputs for each event and there is separate logic for both events based on input. For ex: if 'name' in input is John Doe then add data to database, so basically add data every hour. But if 'name' in input is Jane Doe, then delete all the data, meaning reset the database, once every day. 

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Yea so as a design perspective I would have 2 different lambdas, one thats only purpose is to clean the database once a day.

Answer (score 3):

I am using a config similar to the following, which perfectly works and satisfies my needs.

```yaml
Resources:
  SayHelloWorldRule:
      Type: AWS::Events::Rule
      Properties:
          Description: The rule for greeting the world
          Name: ${self:provider.stage}-say-hello-world-rule
          ScheduleExpression: 'cron(0 7 * * ? *)'
          State: ENABLED
          Targets:
              -
                Arn:
                  !Join [ ':', [ 'arn:aws:lambda', Ref: AWS::Region, Ref: AWS::AccountId, 'function', 'HelloWorldFunction' ] ]
                Id: "GreetTheWorldDaily"
                Input: '{"user": "Sudo user", "message": "Hello world!!!"}'

  SayGoodbyeWorldRule:
      Type: AWS::Events::Rule
      Properties:
          Description: "It's time to say goodbye"
          Name: ${self:provider.stage}-say-goodbye-rule
          ScheduleExpression: 'cron(30 22 * * ? *)'
          State: ENABLED
          Targets:
              -
                Arn:
                    !Join [ ':', [ 'arn:aws:lambda', Ref: AWS::Region, Ref: AWS::AccountId, 'function', 'HelloWorldFunction' ] ]
                Id: "SayGoodbyeDaily"
                Input: '{"user": "Sudo user", "message": "Auf Wiedersehen!!!"}'

  PermissionForEventsToInvokeHelloWorldLambda:
      Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
      Properties:
          FunctionName: HelloWorldFunction
          Action: "lambda:InvokeFunction"
          Principal: "events.amazonaws.com"
```

Answer (score 3):

I might be a little late, but for anyone looking for a similar solution. Just use different names for the trigger.

```
  Events:
    Serverless:
      Type: Api
      Properties:
        Path: /serverless
        Method: get
    FirstConfigScheduledEvent:
      Type: Schedule
      Properties:
        Schedule: cron(30 21 * * ? *)
    SecondConfigScheduledEvent:
      Type: Schedule
      Properties:
        Schedule: cron(30 23 * * ? *)
```

Answer (score 0):

The serverless docs do provide the following aspect to create multiple cron schedules -

```
# the example from our serverless.yml that runs every Monday at 03:15AM UTC
- schedule: cron(15 3 ? * MON *)
# run in 10-minute increments from the start of the hour on all working days
- schedule: cron(1/10 * ? * W *)
# run every day at 6:00PM UTC
- schedule: cron(0 18 * * ? *)
```

---

> You can specify multiple schedule events for each function in case you’d like to combine the schedules. It’s possible to combine rate and cron events on the same function, too.

[Source - Serverless](https://www.serverless.com/blog/cron-jobs-on-aws)

Answer (score 0):

Serverless provides options to achieve this:

```
functions:
  aggregate:
    handler: statistics.handler
    events:
      - schedule:
          rate: rate(10 minutes)
          enabled: false
          input:
            key1: value1
            key2: value2
            stageParams:
              stage: dev
      - schedule:
          rate: cron(0 12 * * ? *)
          enabled: false
          inputPath: '$.stageVariables'
      - schedule:
          rate: rate(2 hours)
          enabled: true
          inputTransformer:
            inputPathsMap:
              eventTime: '$.time'
            inputTemplate: '{"time": <eventTime>, "key1": "value1"}'
```

Reference:- https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/schedule